# Creating simple Google maps with multiple markers to website

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I created google map with multiple markers to my website with "Google My Maps" tool and my code looks like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1PdcME79x-maD5xuiVEi4C777aL4" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

It was really quick and simple without any code writting but what I don't like is the header bar which is showing the name and share button. Can I somehow hide this bar? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the link to the KML from that "MyMap":

```
http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=1PdcME79x-maD5xuiVEi4C777aL4
```

And use that to populate a KmlLayer in a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map:

```
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: "http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=1PdcME79x-maD5xuiVEi4C777aL4",
  map:map
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4cqdeney/1/)

[image: screen shot of result]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: "https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=1PdcME79x-maD5xuiVEi4C777aL4",
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'status_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = kmlLayer.getStatus();
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I understood but how can I get the KML link? When I'm trying to get kml link (export to kml -> whole map) it only downloads me the KML file and there is no link. Can you help me please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mark each area with polygon in google map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875720/how-to-mark-each-area-with-polygon-in-google-map)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get exact coordinates of London zones and use them in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45247439/can-i-get-exact-coordinates-of-london-zones-and-use-them-in-code)